# Enable Special Keys on Toughbook CF-C1?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, tablet

I have a toughbook CF-C1 which is a convertible laptop/tablet machine. There are 6 buttons next to the touch screen designed for use in tablet mode. In Windows they were for things like login (the Windows Security button), rotating the display for different orientations, displaying an on-screen keyboard, changing display brightness, and the last button, labeled USER, I admit I don't know what that one does. The others I find are all very useful however.

On Ubuntu 14.04, I find that none of these buttons work except for the brightness buttons, which act as normal. I tried pressing them in xev, but even there I saw no response whatsoever from the four non-working buttons. Due to my inexperience with its output, I did not really understand the output given by the brightness up/down buttons and I'm not sure where to find exactly where the output begins and ends for pressing them, as such I am at a loss for how to paste them here for reference. If anyone can assist with that then I would be most appreciative.

If anyone has any experience with enabling these special buttons then I would love to hear from them. Thanks!